# Proper way to access a method from runnable

Tags: java, runnable

I have two options to access a method from inside the runnable:

case 1:

```
public class ParentClass{

    private void otherMethod(){
        // some work
        // may call someMethod() from here also
    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            someMethod();
        }

        private void someMethod(){
            // some work
        }
    }   
}
```

case 2:

```
public class ParentClass{

    private void otherMethod(){
        // some work
        // may call someMethod() from here also
    }
    class MyThread implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            someMethod();
        }
    }

    private void someMethod(){
    // some work
    }
{
```

I want to know what are the **pros and cons** of defining **someMehod()** method inside the **MyThread**.

And the difference between the two cases.

Comment: This is not a question for SE.. You should ask this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are doing same thing in both cases.

Comment: It depends on what your classes are and what you are trying to do. That is, this question can not be answered as is.

Answer (score 1):

Easy: use the smallest scope and most restrictive visibility that is required.

If `someMethod()` is only used from `MyThread`, then obviously put it in `MyThread` and make it `private`.

If `ParentClass` also uses `someMethod()`, put it in `ParentClass`. If `someMethod()` is only called from `ParentClass` and from `MyThread`, make it `private`. If it is called from other package classes (same package), make it package private or `protected`. If it is called from subclasses too, make it `protected`. If it is called from other packages too, make it `public`.